# Pass environment variable in docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wonder if it is possible to pass environment variables to docker-compose.yml using docker-compose up without using an .env file. I know that it is possible to pass environment variables using docker run but I don't want use it.

Update:
For example this is my one of the part docker-compose file:

```
db:
   container_name: mysql
   image: mysql:5.7
   restart: always
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

And when I try run

> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root docker-compose up

I have got error:

> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root : The term 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path i
> s correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root docker-compose up
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

If you have a docker-compose file like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  myservice:
    image: debian
    command: echo ${MYENV}
```

and run it with

```
MYENV=Hello docker-compose up
```

The container will print `Hello`.

Comment: I tried this method but this doesn't work for me. Look updated question.

Comment: My solution works on Linux. It sounds like you're using Windows and Powershell.

Comment: Hmm probably this could be the problem, ok thanks for your answers

Comment: I don't know Powershell, so I can't help with that. But if you can find a way to set an environment variable before running docker-compose, it should work the same way